# Copy and paste if one cell is blank and the other is not

Tags: excel, vba

So data gets pasted in to column B as the code keeps running it'll do a condition check to see there's any values in column B and paste a value in to the adjacent column A. I need to make it so it does two condition checks:

If there's values in column b, but then to check if there's values in column A before pasting so it doesn't overwrite different data that's been pasted already.

```
For Each Cell In y.Sheets("Compiled").Range("A:B")
    If Range("B:B").Value <> "" And Range("A:A").Value = "" Then
    Cell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, don't try to loop over a multiple column range:

```
Sub Test()

For Each Cell In y.Sheets("Compiled").Range("B:B")
    If Cell.Value <> "" And Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Cell.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**NOTE:** You are looping through every cell in `Range("B:B")` which is *probably* unnecessary. It'd be better if you use a `lastrow` value, or a static range like `Range("B2:B1000")`. Or you could use a criteria to exit your loop like `If Cell.Value = "" Then Exit For`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just assign the value `Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Cell.Value` instead of special pasting it?

Comment: I didn't see he was pasting as value, so you are correct :)

Comment: Thank you! Your note was helpful and you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of the code that implements the lastrow value that dwirony mentioned in their answer. This also throws everything in arrays, so it might go a bit faster if you have a really large dataset.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim ACol As Variant
    Dim BCol As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lastrow = Range("B:B").Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    BCol = Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Value
    ACol = Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value

    For i = LBound(BCol) To UBound(BCol)
        If IsEmpty(ACol(i, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(BCol(i, 1)) Then
            ACol(i, 1) = BCol(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Value = ACol
End Sub
```